# Инициализатор поля не может обращаться к нестатическому полю методу или свойству

Tags: c#

Добрый день.

Пытаюсь в классе public partial class Form1 : Form создать static переменную и присвоить ей значение из numericUpDown1.Value.

Пример:

private static int ThreadCount = (int)numericUpDown1.Value;

Вылетает ошибка: "Инициализатор поля не может обращаться к нестатическому полю методу или свойству". Как можно обойти это ограничение?

Comment: А вы уверены, что вам нужна именно статическая переменная?

Comment: Не принципиально, можно и обычную переменную использовать.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Всё ж написано в коде ошибки. Вы создаёте статическую переменную, значение которой должно быть определено заранее. А в качестве инициализатора используете переменную, значение которой будет известно только во время исполнения кода. Разнестите инициализацию и присваивание, и будет вам счастье :)

Comment: По другому никак? Неужели нет возможности сделать проще?

Comment: Что значит проще? Подумайте, какое значение будет у numericUpDown1.Value до того, как программа запущена на выполнение? Да такой переменной ещё не существует в принципе :) А ThreadCount в этот момент уже есть, и чем его инициализировать? Так что ваш код просто не имеет права на существование и не будет скомпилирован. Вообще никак, забудьте про него.

Answer (score 0):

Можно дать ссылку, чтобы не инициализировать ничего

```
private int ThreadCount => (int)numericUpDown1.Value
```